# Create UIView Subclass Without Init() - Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uiview, core-graphics

I have a UIView subclass which contains only the following:

```
drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let ctx: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let radius: CGFloat = rect.width / 2
    let endAngle = CGFloat(2 * M_PI)
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, bounds.width / 2, bounds.height / 2, radius, 0, endAngle, 1)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 4.0)
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke)
}
```

I do not call any init() functions, but the object is still drawn.

Additionally, when I attempt to implement an init() function, I am given several errors regarding required initializations.

So my question is : How am I able to create a UIView object without an init() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializers are inherited. Your superclass (`UIView`) has `init` already defined so your class inherits them by default.

Once you define `init`, your class won't inherit superclass initializers any more so you will have to define all the required ones.

Comment: Just to clarify : If I define what is required, and call super.init() I can override the init() function?

Comment: @BrandonBradley Yes, you can. However, for `UIView` is more common to override `init(frame:)` which is the designated initializer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information. Still fairly new to this.